# FD reuse in socketpair and forking

Tags: python, sockets

I try to programe a prefork server for study which I found os.fork will reuse FD number.

Although the output is correct, but I wounding is **WHY**

Here is code and output

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

import os
import socket
import time

def main():


    for x in xrange(4):
        parent_sock, children_sock = socket.socketpair()
        #parent_sock.setblocking(0)
        #children_sock.setblocking(0)
        pid = os.fork()

        if pid != 0:
            print os.getpid(), "M->parent", parent_sock.fileno()
            print os.getpid(), "M->children", children_sock.fileno()
            parent_sock.send('HI %d' % pid)

        else:
            #child
            print os.getpid(), "C->parent", parent_sock.fileno()
            print os.getpid(), "C->child", children_sock.fileno()
            time.sleep(3)
            print children_sock.fileno(), children_sock.recv(4096)
            return


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As you can see it just a normal preforking server code, and I use time.sleep to disable python destroy the child_sock. 
But why both child process using fileno 4, 6 still getting the right answer?

```
$python fork.py
16414 M->parent 3
16414 M->children 4
16415 C->parent 3
16415 C->child 4
16414 M->parent 5
16414 M->children 6
16416 C->parent 5
16416 C->child 6
16414 M->parent 3
16414 M->children 4
16417 C->parent 3
16417 C->child 4
16414 M->parent 5
16414 M->children 6
16418 C->parent 5
16418 C->child 6

$4 HI 16415
6 HI 16416
4 HI 16417
6 HI 16418
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Garbage collection.

In every `for` iteration in parent, local variables `parent_sock` and `children_sock` point to the newly created sockets, and the previous values are not reachable anymore, so Python may choose to close and reuse the old sockets.

If you store all the sockets somewhere, it prevents Python to do garbage collection and thus it does not close them, and you will see different numbers.

I mean: this code can reuse some FD numbers:

```
for x in xrange(4):
    parent_sock, children_sock = socket.socketpair()
    print "M->parent", parent_sock.fileno()
    print "M->children", children_sock.fileno()
```

but this code cannot:

```
list_sockets = []
for x in xrange(4):
    parent_sock, children_sock = socket.socketpair()
    list_sockets.append([parent_sock, children_sock])
    print "M->parent", parent_sock.fileno()
    print "M->children", children_sock.fileno()
```